# OpenShift repo//package.json error

Tags: node.js, openshift

I can't push my commit to openshift server. I've got this error:

```
remote: [eval]:1
    remote: var p = require('/var/lib/openshift/578a15de2d527132bd00009e/app-root/runtime/repo//package.json'); console.log(p.scripts.start);
    remote:                                                                                                                          ^
    remote:
    remote: TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
    remote:     at [eval]:1:122
    remote:     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:25:33)
    remote:     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:77:17)
    remote:     at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    remote:     at bootstrap_node.js:315:29
    remote:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    remote:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    remote: CLIENT_MESSAGE: Stopping Node.js application...
    Connection to ______.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How to solve this. Any advices, please.

Comment: Same problem, did you find a fix?

Comment: Yes I did. Problem was solved by restoring the start.js file. Don't delete that file, openshift server uses that to start workers.

Comment: I resolved differently, i wanted using the correct port, i was using the one that worked on my pc but not the configured server port (the start.js isnt needed). I setup that start script as simply

    `"scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    }`